# Desktop suddenly turned off and won't turn on again

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

My desktop suddenly shut down and it does not turn on again. I have tested the PSU with the paperclip trick and the fan started to spin. What do I do from here to know what is broken? There is no response whatsoever when I press the power button when the PSU is connected to the motherboard.

Comment: paperclip trick does not qualify the psu is good under load, try another psu.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware failure.  It sounds like it could either be the motherboard or the CPU, which one it is, impossible to tell based on the information you can provide.  As explained the problem could still be the PSU though.  Eliminate the cheaper components first as being the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnect everything except the power supply from the motherboard and try it by itself.  If it powers on, start adding parts back in until you find the one that makes it fail.

Comment: When I disconnected the front usb 3.0 cable the pc could start. The front usb 3.0 ports were already not working because one physically broke 1-2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Jump it with the paperclip, then test your cables to make sure they're getting the correct voltage.  [image]

It may also be that the PSU isn't getting a good PWR_OK signal.  You'll need a [tester](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0U00YF4753&cm_re=psu_tester-_-9SIA0U00YF4753-_-Product) to determine that as the timing is in the millisecond range.

You can also try using another known good PSU to try it to see if it's the PSU or the motherboard causing issues.

Comment: This does not do a load test on the psu an does not qualify the psu as good.